# Listbox.Selected shows run time error '-2147024809(80070057)'

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, selected

I have a listbox which is set to multi select.
When I use listbox.selected to check the item selection status、I get the run time error.
Run-time error '-2147024809(80070057)':Could not get selected property. Invalid argument.

There are 55 items set in the listbox. And when i=25, the error happens.
What is the cause of this error?

```
' Add item to listbox
with me
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
      .ListBox1.AddItem arr(i)
    Next
End With

' Check listbox
with me
    arr = Array()
    For i = 0 To .ListBox1.ListCount - 1
      If .ListBox1.Selected(i) = False Then    <-Error happen here
        ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
        arr(UBound(arr)) = .ListBox1.List(i)
      End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: How is the `arr` variable declared? Do you try what you show us in a single procedure, or in two? Is there `Option Explicit` on top of the form code module?

Comment: arr is declared as variant.
Process "Add item to listbox"  and Check listbox process  are processed by two functions.
Ant there is Option Explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error disappeared after recreating the form and all related processing,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).